# Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL cron daemon not running after reboot

Tags: cron, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS running under Windows 10 Pro. After every reboot, the cron daemon is not started.

I can start it manually with `sudo service cron start`.

What can I configure or what system file I need to modify so that after a reboot, the cron daemon starts?

Comment: After booting try `journalctl | grep cron` to see if errors are reported.

Comment: Hello, Tulio, did you succeed with this task?

Comment: Makes perfect sense to control service activation thru Windows Task Scheduler. My next reboot opportunity is next weekend, so I'll report my results then.

Comment: Success - Instructions worked perfectly for admin permissions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As it is described in the article [Starting Linux Background Services on Windows Login](https://dev.to/ironfroggy/wsl-tips-starting-linux-background-services-on-windows-login-3o98) you need to trigger your command `sudo service cron start` from Windows. You can use Windows Task Scheduler for this purpose. Here are the steps from the mentioned article with a slight modifications:

**1.** Create startup script and make it executable:

```
echo "service cron start" | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/cronstart.sh
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cronstart.sh
```

Thus `cronstart.sh` will be accessible as shell command system wide.

**2.** Create a file within `/etc/sudoers.d/` with purpose to allow your `$USER` to execute `cronstart.sh` by `sudo` **without password**. Run the following command to generate the line that must be placed in the sudoers file:

```
echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/cronstart.sh"
```

[Copy](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165972/566421) the output of the command, use the command **`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/cronstart`** and paste the copied line as content of the newly created file. [Save the file and exit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password/159009#159009).

**3.** Within Windows, go to the search bar, find and run ***Task Scheduler*** (as administrator if your current account isn't administrators one).

Now, click ***Task Scheduler Library*** on the left and then ***Create Task…*** on the right to create a new task. You can use the following parameters to configure the task:

- **General tab**:

  ***Name*** the task anything you want, like `WSL service cron start`.

  Choice the option ***Run whether user is logged or not***.

  Mark ***Do not store password*** and ***Run with highest privileges***.

  In the ***Configure for*** dropdown select ***`Windows 10`***.

  If you need to setup a task for another user click on the button `Change User or Group...`.
- **Triggers tab**:

  Click ***New…*** to add a new trigger for this task.

  In the ***Begin the task*** dropdown select ***`At startup`***.

  Within the *Advanced settings* you can check ***Delay task for `1 minute`***.
- **Actions tab**:

  Click ***New…*** to add a new action for this task.

  Pick ***Start a program*** for the action type and then enter ***`C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe`*** as the program to run.

  At ***Add arguments (optional)*** set this: ***`sudo cronstart.sh`***.

That’s it. Reboot the system, then open WLS terminal and use `service cron status` to check whether `cron is running`.

---

*I've made some tests and unfortunately I found Windows 10 experiences some bugs and it is <s>almost</s> impossible to setup such task for a non-administrator user's account, while you are using Windows account instead of local one ... complete mess :O*

As workaround in this case you can create a file called **`cronstart.bat`** in the folder [`shell:startup`](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=151) with content as follow:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe sudo cronstart.sh
```

How to use VBS instead of a bat file to achieve the same result is shown here:

- [Windows Subsystem for Linux Autoload Apache2 and MySql](https://askubuntu.com/a/1020925/566421)

Comment: also you can use Task Scheduler > https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177273/wsl-ubuntu-is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-bash-start-automatically-on-windows-sta

Comment: Sudoers part is not needed anymore as we can run commands as root: `wsl.exe -u root my_command`

Answer (score 7):

A new feature in Windows 11, assuming you can upgrade, is the ability to specify startup tasks for WSL using the `/etc/wsl.conf` file.  If you have Windows 11, create that file with the following lines:

```
[boot]
command="service cron start"
```

According to the [Microsoft doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#boot-settings), this will run the command as root when the WSL instance starts.

If you need to run multiple commands at WSL startup, separate them with semicolons in the same `command` line:

```
[boot]
command="service ssh start; service cron start"
```

You would still need to run WSL in a *Windows* startup task of some sort (as mentioned in the previous answer) in order to trigger the `boot` options, but this task can now be something as simple as `wsl -e true`.  This will run the `true` command and then simply exit, but will also trigger the `boot` command.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found and its seems to work perfectly and only takes 2 min to setup is described
[here](https://blog.snowme34.com/post/schedule-tasks-using-crontab-on-windows-10-with-wsl/index.html)

In short:

1. Execute shell:startup in the basice windows shell application
2. This will open the folder "C:\Users****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
3. Add shorcut "wsl.exe" with the target "C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe sudo /etc/init.d/cron start"
4. Edit you sudo config file via "sudo visudo"
5. Add "%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/cron start" to the file to prevent admin password for the cron service