# Is there an easy way to have WSL Ubuntu services start automatically on Windows startup?

Tags: startup, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a question about the WSL version of Ubuntu. Is there an easy way to have bash start automatically when Windows starts and pass a command to it to start the SSH server? So that the SSH server runs all the time when Windows runs.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165969/ubuntu-18-04-on-wsl-cron-daemon-not-running-after-reboot Related post. Also works for WSL 2 and windows 10. (for me at least) It's the same approach with the wsl.exe in the startup folder of windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This also works on WSL 2.

#### Solution 1: use VBE script

Click on Start and search for shell:startup.
also you can go manually to:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

now create a new file `sshserver.vbe` and add this text and save:

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
ws.run "wsl -d Ubuntu -u root service ssh start", vbhide
```

#### Solution 2: Task Scheduler

Click on Start and search for Task Scheduler.

1. On Task Scheduler  click on **Action** and select **Create Basic Task**

   [image]
2. On Create Basic Task Fill out Name and Description "Auto Start SSH server"

   [image: create Basic Task]
3. On Trigger select: When the computer starts.

   [image: Trigger]
4. On Action select Start a program

   [image: Action]
5. On Start a Program type path: `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe`,
   next on add Add arguments (optional): `-d Ubuntu -u root service ssh start`.

   [image: Start a Program]

You should have something like this on the last step.

[image: finish]

Comment: When I try this command I get: "/bin/bash: -d: invalid option". When I remove -d Ubuntu but keep -u root there is a similar error. With "wsl service ssh start" it runs as a non-root user and fails. "wsl sudo service ssh start" asks for a password so it cannot be autorun at startup. Perhaps after editing visudo/sudoers it could work...

Comment: use wsl not bash if you look close all my calls was made from windows not inside Linux. correct one:  C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -u root service ssh start

Comment: i forgot to mention this it's for  wsl 2

Comment: another solutin to use bash it's to add in your  /etc/sudoers this : <<  username  >>  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL , replace <<  username  >> with your username then call: C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "sudo service ssh start"

Comment: I thought WSL2 was still in beta?

Comment: So wsl.exe on my laptop is an older version probably. Also, all Linux processes are killed when the shell exits. This command works for me: "wsl.exe sh -c 'sudo /usr/sbin/service ssh start; cat'", adding cat keeps the ssh server running. I used 'visudo' to add this line to sudoers: "<username> ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service ssh start" (only running this command is allowed without a password). Later I will try if it works on Windows startup using one of the methods.

Comment: Yes it works on startup, using the method with Startup folder and VB script (with wsl command changed like in the previous comment). Thanks for the help.

Comment: C:\Users\<< username >>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

on windows 10 home ver 1909 the dir location is different to above.
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

Comment: how can I do in not WSL 2?