# How to start a specific service when Ubuntu is started on WSL2

Tags: startup, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to run `sudo service postgresql start` every time when I start Ubuntu on WSL2.

How can I make the service start automatically when I start Ubuntu?

WSL doesn't use systemd, so `sudo systemctl enable postgresql` doesn't work.

```
$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). 
Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Is there a standard way to start a service at startup?

#### Edit

I want to start the service on Ubuntu startup, not on Windows startup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSL Ubuntu, is there an easy way to have bash start automatically on Windows startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177273/wsl-ubuntu-is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-bash-start-automatically-on-windows-sta)

Comment: (If you didn't mean start on boot, but only when you run WSL, then just putting `sudo service postgresql start` in your `.bashrc` should work fine.)

Comment: I just want to start a service when WSL is launched. And I'd avoid to `sudo` command in `.bashrc`. In that way I always need to type my password when I open new tabs.

Comment: You'd add a NOPASSWD rule for just this command, so you won't be prompted for a password.

Comment: I added `ironsand ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service postgresql` to `/etc/sudoer` and restart wsl, but I still need to enter password every time. Maybe this is another question, should I open a new question?

Comment: If you use an argument to the command, then it must match the command line exactly (`sudo service postgresql` != `sudo service postgresql start`. Try adding the `start` to the sudoers line as well.  You shouldn't have to restart WSL, changes to `sudoers` take effect immediately.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With the recent release of Windows 11, there are two preferred ways to do this.

##### Windows 11

You can now execute an arbitrary command line when starting an instance by creating/editing `/etc/wsl.conf` (via sudo) with the following:

```
[boot]
command="service postgresql start"
```

This command runs as root and generates no output.  If you need to run multiple commands, they should be semicolon separated (or something like `&&`) inside the `command=` string.

##### Windows 10

On WSL with Windows 10, there's still an easier way, IMHO, than putting a `sudo` command in your startup and worrying about `sudoers`.

`sudoers` is certainly the canonical (no pun intended, just a happy accident) way to do it on Ubuntu, but on WSL it's just easier to use the following syntax in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
 wsl.exe -u root service postgresql status || wsl.exe -u root service postgresql start
```

`wsl.exe -u root` doesn't require a password.  From PowerShell and CMD, it can be called without the `exe`, but from within WSL it does require the extension.

Note, per [@mbomb007](https://askubuntu.com/users/867283/mbomb007)'s comment, this will generate one or two messages every time you start.  To suppress this, use:

```
wsl.exe -u root service postgresql status > /dev/null || wsl.exe -u root service postgresql start > /dev/null
```

Comment: To avoid seeing output every time you open WSL, use `wsl.exe -u root service postgresql status > /dev/null || wsl.exe -u root service postgresql start > /dev/null` instead.

Comment: Windows 11 solution doesn't work for me.. service is still inactive. I can tell it loads slower before it shows `Sleeping for 1 second to let systemd settle` though.

Comment: @Jeppe It sounds like you are using a Systemd script -- Perhaps WSL2Hacks or Genie?  That's going to change a *lot* of behavior on your system.  If you have Systemd "working", though, just use the normal `systemctl` methods to autostart -- Something like `sudo systemctl enable <servicename>`.  But strongly recommend you understand the possible caveats you can run into with Systemd under WSL2.  This is just one of many things that will be different.

Comment: It seems to happen on all instances I create of Ubuntu 18.04. I haven't added scripts like that.

Comment: @Jeppe Recommend you open a new question, then, but ["Sleeping for 1 second to let systemd settle"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Sleeping%20for%201%20second%20to%20let%20systemd%20settle%22), as you can see in that search, is almost certainly coming from [DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script](https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script).  If you aren't installing it yourself, then please include information in your question about how you installed Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL, because the script definitely seems to be getting installed on your system somehow.  Thanks!

Comment: While it works for postgres, it doesn't for apache2. I had to use `pgrep apache2 > /dev/null || wsl.exe -u root -- service apache2 start > /dev/null`

Comment: @ArtemP True - Different services will need different startup methods on different distributions.  I'll edit the answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

At least as of March 2023 WSL2 now supports systemd ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#systemd-support)), also on Windows 10. Just put

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

in your /etc/wsl.conf.
After a reboot you can enable services via systemctl.