# Open Ubuntu terminal using batch file on windows with command?

Tags: command-line, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I automate many processes on windows using batch files and putty.

E.g ( login_server7.bat ):

`start C:\Users\Jack\Documents\putty.exe -ssh 1.1.1.1 -l user123 -pw "bleh"`

How am I able to start an Ubuntu terminal and run a command automatically after opening a file?

Rather than manually opening the ubuntu terminal and typing my commands in?

Cannot see anything elsewhere on this topic. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable of WSL is `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe`. You can just type `wsl` in Windows Command prompt and you will be logged-in to the default WSL instance. Or type `wsl -h` in order to get the list of all available options. In batch files you can use:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe <your script or command>
```

Or if you need to run the command as root:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe sudo <your script or command>
```

Probably more correct way is to use `wsl -e -- <command>`, but the above works nice for me. Here is more detailed example: [Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL cron daemon not running after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1165969/566421).

Answer (score 2):

As `ps4080`'s answer mentions, the right way to do this is `wsl -e -- <command>` (or, typically `wsl -e <command>`).

However, there are actually quite a few nuances you might run into with this technique, and it's nice to understand what's going on with each exact incantation so you can use the right one when needed:

##### `wsl <command>`

- Runs the default shell for the current user
- ... as a non-login, non-interactive shell
- ... in the directory passed in by the owning Windows process
- Runs `<command>` in that shell

Depending on your shell, you can see this with `wsl ps -eH`:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 init
   18 ?        00:00:00   init
   19 ?        00:00:00     init
   20 pts/0    00:00:00       fish
   28 pts/0    00:00:00         ps
```

Note that it's difficult to see this when `bash` is your default shell since `-c` results in an implicit `exec`.

The fact that this runs in the directory of the owning Windows process can be handy, since you can do:

```
wsl ls -lh
```

... in PowerShell to get "human readable" file sizes, something that is [surprisingly difficult to do](https://superuser.com/q/468782/1210833) otherwise.

The trickiest part of this is that second qualifier.  WSL runs your shell as a non-login, non-interactive shell when started this way.  This means that `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` are *not* sourced on startup.  This can cause confusion when attempting to run a command that requires something to be done in the startup files (e.g. setting an environment variable).

##### `wsl -e <command>`

- Runs `<command>` *as* the shell
- ... in the directory passed in by the owning process

The `-e` bypasses your default shell entirely.

```
> wsl ps -eH
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 init
    7 ?        00:00:00   init
    8 ?        00:00:00     init
    9 pts/0    00:00:00       ps
```

This can be *slightly* more efficient since you avoid the startup overhead of the shell, but it's typically not worth worrying about.

##### `wsl -e bash -lic <command>`

- Runs `bash` as your shell (regardless of whether it is the default shell or not)
- Forces it to be a login, interactive shell (`-li`) so that `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` (and/or others) are sourced
- ... in the directory passed in by the owning Windows process
- Runs `<command>` in that shell

This is the version to use if the command needs anything from your startup configuration.