# Using a batch file on Windows to automate Ubuntu in WSL

Tags: 20.04, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, batch

I'd like to automate Ubuntu through a single-click batch file in Windows.

I can just `start ubuntu`, but if I add `/k cd "path"`, it just doesn't do anything.  It exits with no error.

I'd like to do an automation so that I can click a batch file in Windows and:

- open Ubuntu in WSL
- cd to path
- activate an environment
- `cargo run`
- ... and then leave Ubuntu running in the same instance

... but WSL doesn't seem to behave as I'd expect. I don't understand.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382572/open-ubuntu-terminal-using-batch-file-on-windows-with-command) is really close, but I have tried it and can't get it to work.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1411013/edit) and add all the information. It is not clear which version of Windows (10/11) and which version of Ubuntu you are running. Please indicate if you are using WSL (1 or 2?) or a virtual machine like VMWare or VirtualBox to run Ubuntu. Please copy the `bat` file and paste it directly in your question above and format is as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window. Tell us more about the app `cargo`. Is it a commandline app or an app that needs a GUI for Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe [this question and answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1578661/how-to-start-wsl-in-windows-terminal-programmatically-and-run-command) will help you.

Comment: to me this is a windows problem as the problem seems to be batch programming IN windows.

Comment: @Rinzwind Not as much as you might think - It's a one-liner batch file to call WSL and launch Ubuntu.  The script itself is all Bash/Ubuntu, and is the same that one would execute from the Bash in Ubuntu without WSL involved.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, it sounds like you want to script a series of commands in WSL/Ubuntu, but leave the shell open after they are done.

The key steps are:

- Use the `wsl` command, not the `ubuntu.exe` command.
- Start the shell in which you are going to run the commands with `-lic`, which will make it both a login shell (to parse your `~/.bash_profile`) and an interactive shell (to parse your `~/.bashrc`).
- Separate the commands with semicolons in the `wsl` arguments.
- To keep a shell running after, make the final command `exec bash`

For example:

```
wsl -e bash -lic "cd /home/myhome/src/project ; source /home/myhome/src/myproject/bin/activate ; cargo run ; exec bash"
```